# Symfony2: Overriding a built-in field type with a custom field type having the same name

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

As per [this article](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/create_custom_field_type.html) on the Symfony docs, I've created a custom field type, set it up in `services.yml`, and I am able to use it successfully.

For example, I create a custom field named `customdate` as follows, which works perfectly:

```
# src/Acme/DemoBundle/Resources/config/services.yml
services:
    acme_demo.form.type.date:
        class: Acme\DemoBundle\Form\Type\DateType
        tags:
            - { name: form.type, alias: customdate }
```

However, if I try to name my custom field as `date` (which is the same as [an existing Symfony field type](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/date.html), since this is what I am trying to override), as shown below, then Symfony completely ignores my custom field, and defaults to the built-in Symfony `date` field type instead:

```
# src/Acme/DemoBundle/Resources/config/services.yml
services:
    acme_demo.form.type.date:
        class: Acme\DemoBundle\Form\Type\DateType
        tags:
            - { name: form.type, alias: date }
```

I've checked that my `getName()` function returns the correct name, matching up with the alias I provided in `services.yml`.

The code in which I make use of the above services follows below.

This works:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('date', 'customdate')));
}
```

This does not work: (or rather, Symfony uses the built-in field type instead of mine)

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('date', 'date')));
}
```

I should note that if I replace the 'customdate' or 'date' with a manually-created object such as `new Date()` then it works fine. The problem appears to be specifically that Symfony prefers its built-in field types over the ones that are specified in `services.yml`.

**My question:** is there any way to override built-in Symfony field types with custom field types that have the same name? Clearly, from what I described above, Symfony appears to ignore any custom fields that are aliased to the same name as a built-in Symfony field type. Is there any way around this?

Comment: Out of curiosity why do you want it named the same thing? Why is using the custom name not an option?

Comment: Using a custom name is an acceptable alternative if it isn't possible to override the existing field type. The reason I would _like_ to have it named the same is because logically it still represents the same type of data as the built-in `date` field, and so there would be no added cognitive load in having to remember the name of the custom field. The problem is that the built-in `date` field type is somewhat limited when it comes to custom date formats, as noted in this issue on GitHub: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/8345

Comment: From what i can tell the format issue has been fixed, what format are you trying to use that wont let you?

Comment: The format I need, by example, is 01 Jan 2014. Basically, if using the PHP `date()` function, the following: `date('d M Y')`

Comment: that would be accomplished with `'format'=>'d MMM Y'`. Date parsed by the IntlDateFormatter class. Valid formats can be found [here](http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/datetime#TOC-Date-Time-Format-Syntax)

Comment: Looks like I misunderstood the format string, so I ended up asking the wrong question entirely. Your solution is correct. Thank you!

Comment: should be possible with a compiler pass, http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/override.html#services-configuration
I'm trying it now, let you know how it goes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i know there is no way to truly override the base field types, you can inherit them and use your own name.

However if the field type that you want to override is not providing the functionality you think it should there is likely an issue with that type that should be reported.

For your case the date type doesnt take typical php date() format string. From looking at the documentation **[here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/date.html#format)** we see that the date format is parsed by the IntlDateFormatter class. For valid formats check out **[this list](http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/datetime#TOC-Date-Time-Format-Syntax)**.

To accomplish the format you want `date('d M Y')` you would use:

```
$builder->add('my_date_field', 'date', array(
    'format'=>'d MMM Y'
));
```

Comment: Interestingly, although my particular requirement is solved with your suggestion, it seems that there is still a limitation in the formatting options, namely limited to combinations of d, M and y, and not the full range of symbols that are documented in the link you provided (which is the same reference that Symfony docs point to as well).

Attempting to use any other symbols results in an InvalidOptionsException being thrown. See:

https://github.com/symfony/symfony/commit/5b057f89b0799933c9223e93e8641eb4fad12cc8#diff-a10493dac3dc022ac1a8a9b2fd184840R54

Comment: The full range of symbols also includes time, which you would use `datetime` for. Do you have another specific example that it wouldnt support?

Comment: Ah, yes you're correct. Other symbols do work. The GitHub link I provided merely shows that 'd', 'M', and 'y' are the bare minimum required symbols in order to be unambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the first question there is a way to override the built in symfony form types. The above code is almost correct. It just needs to use the same service id as used in symfony. See the [Symfony service config](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.8/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Resources/config/form.xml#L79) and use the same service id:

```
# src/Acme/DemoBundle/Resources/config/services.yml
services:
    form.type.date:
        class: Acme\DemoBundle\Form\Type\DateType
        tags:
            - { name: form.type, alias: date }
```

I've tested this and seems to work fine. `Acme\DemoBundle\Form\Type\DateType` should extend the symfony class `Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\DateType` with whatever changes are needed. This can be done with any Symfony form type.

Another approach slightly more complicated but more future proof is using a complier pass to change the class of the service definition but leave the rest unchanged. It looks like:

```
//src/Acme/DemoBundle/DependencyInjection/Compiler/OverrideServiceCompilerPass.php
namespace Acme\DemoBundle\DependencyInjection\Compiler;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\CompilerPassInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;

class OverrideServiceCompilerPass implements CompilerPassInterface
{
    public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $definition = $container->getDefinition('form.type.date');
        $definition->setClass('Acme\DemoBundle\Form\Type\DateType');
    }
}
```

then the compiler pass is registered in the AcmeDemoBundle class like;

```
// src/Acme/DemoBundle/AcmeDemoBundle.php
namespace Acme\DemoBundle;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;

use Acme\DemoBundle\DependencyInjection\Compiler\OverrideServiceCompilerPass;

class AcmeDemoBundle extends Bundle
{
    public function build(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        parent::build($container);

        $container->addCompilerPass(new OverrideServiceCompilerPass());
    }
}
```

See [overriding services doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/override.html#services-configuration) and [compiler pass doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/compiler_passes.html) for more information.