# Symfony2: overriding a built-in field type with a custom field type having the same name. Part 2

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I work with Symfony 2.8.3

I've read these resources:

- [How to Create a Custom Form Field Type](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/create_custom_field_type.html)
- [Symfony2: Overriding a built-in field type with a custom field type having the same name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22673275/symfony2-overriding-a-built-in-field-type-with-a-custom-field-type-having-the-s)

and some other ones which were mentioned in them.

It's necessary to create such 'date'  field type which would satisfy the customer in many parameters including format.
And this field type (created by me) must be used everywhere in the project even in other bundles.

I create a class:

```
class DateType extends \Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\DateType {
    // Here I overload the necessary methods
}
```

Register it in services:

```
services:
    #...
    form.type.date:
        class: Application\Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\DateType
        tags:
            - { name: form.type, alias: date }
    #...
```

and use it in a form:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('birthday', 'date', array(
            'widget' => 'single_text',
            'label' => 'form.label.birthday',
            'translation_domain' => $this->translation_domain,
            'required' => true,
            'invalid_message' => 'form.error.birthday',
            'attr' => array(
                'class' => 'datepicker without-error-text',
            ),
            'format' => 'dd-MM-yyyy',
        ));
}
```

However this code throws an exception:

> The field type "Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\DateType" is not registered with the service container.

What does it mean, 'not registered'? Ah, yeah, not registered.
That's because I registered my field type instead of the built-in one.

One of the resources that I've shown above has an advice regarding how to register customer's type forcibly.

Ok, let's do it.

I create a self compiler:

```
namespace Acme\DemoBundle\DependencyInjection\Compiler;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\CompilerPassInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;

class OverrideServiceCompilerPass implements CompilerPassInterface
{
    public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $definition = $container->getDefinition('form.type.date');
        $definition->setClass('Acme\DemoBundle\Form\Type\DateType');
    }
}
```

Use it while building the main bundle:

```
// src/Acme/DemoBundle/AcmeDemoBundle.php
namespace Acme\DemoBundle;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;

use Acme\DemoBundle\DependencyInjection\Compiler\OverrideServiceCompilerPass;

class AcmeDemoBundle extends Bundle
{
    public function build(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        parent::build($container);

        $container->addCompilerPass(new OverrideServiceCompilerPass());
    }
}
```

But it's still unsuccessful. That code throws an exception again but this time it was different:

> The type name specified for the service "form.type.date" does not match the actual name.
> Expected "Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\DateType",
> given "Application\Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\DateType"

After researching the code I find out that the Sonata Project throws  the exception from
its different bundles. In my project I use Sonata Admin and Sonata Blocks. These bundles can't create custom
date type field in their forms. Because they receive different names of classes.

```
//vendor\sonata-project\core-bundle\Form\Extension\DependencyInjectionExtension.php
// this block: if ($name !== get_class($type) && (method_exists($type, 'getName') && $type->getName() !== $name)) {...}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function getType($name)
{
    // resolve code to FQCN
    $name = self::findClass($this->mappingTypes, $name);

    if (!isset($this->typeServiceIds[$name])) {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException(sprintf('The field type "%s" is not registered with the service container.', $name));
    }

    $type = $this->container->get($this->typeServiceIds[$name]);

    if ($name !== get_class($type) && (method_exists($type, 'getName') && $type->getName() !== $name)) {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException(
            sprintf('The type name specified for the service "%s" does not match the actual name. Expected "%s", given "%s"',
                $this->typeServiceIds[$name],
                $name,
                get_class($type)
            ));
    }

    return $type;
}
```

And now tell me please what I do wrong.